# How can I train my ANFIS dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, fuzzy-logic

I have some following dataset of 9 years that represents the people per infected of dengue from 2007 to 2015 divide in four quadrant in each year. How can I prepare my dataset for ANFIS. and train them to predict previous year record ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an FIS with **N** inputs, training data has **N+1** columns, where the first **N** columns contain input data and the final column contains output data. Here you can choose to have **2** inputs (the **year** and the **quadrant**) and one output (the **value**). In this way for **9** years, the number of rows becomes **36**. The number of columns is equal to the number of inputs + output (**2+1**).

```
a = 1:4;
b = (2007:2015)';
[A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
A = A(:);
B = B(:);
C = ones(36,1); % you should insert your numbers here from the table
trainData = [B A C]
```

Now try to use `genfis` to generate a FIS:

```
numMFs = 5;   % number of membership function
mfType = 'gbellmf'; % type of MF
fis = genfis1(trainData,numMFs,mfType);
```

the more compact way becomes:

```
[A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
trainData = [A(:) B(:) C];
```